# how to change main page categories and images in open cart

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module

[These categories are not responding to categories change in dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mRDT.png)

I deleted all the categories but still these are not affected. plz help me in that.

Comment: what is the name of the module you are using?

Comment: you need to search in the admin panel and find from where is being set,

Comment: OC version not provided

Comment: It's something with your theme, not with OpenCart.

Answer (score 0):

Check modules settings in dashboard. It could be some of menu module or your theme module.

Answer (score -1):

When you asking about opencart you should provide which version of OC you are use. A lot of differences between versions .

Comment: if you do not understand OpenCart system it is not smart to give me (-)... When you asking some question regarding opencart, you always should provide OC version you are using... Nobody help you if OC version not provided.